# Metal Gear on NES: Are the rules for opening doors in the game an algorithm?

Tags: history, nintendo

In the NES Game [Metal Gear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_%28video_game%29) from year 1987, the player uses 8 cards to open doors in the game. Considering the small amount of memory (both ROM and RAM) on the NES, it seems reasonable (or, at least, possible) to expect that the rules for opening doors in the game are expressed in the form of a **short** piece of code. The mapping between card numbers and doors is - for the purposes of such a game - **arbitrary**. An algorithm may have smaller memory footprint than an explicit representation of the card-door mapping in computer memory. In addition, writing a simple algorithm **once** is much more productive (in terms of human resources needed to finish the game) than having to decide on and enter several numbers for each of the screens that have one or more doors.

Are the rules for opening doors in the game expressed as an algorithm, or is it just plain data?

Comment: 8 cards means that only a byte of information is needed per door. Doesn't seem too much to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Metal Gear for NES there are eleven kinds of doors (locked doors, elevator doors, doors that open when punched and plain unlocked doors).  I'm not sure how Metal Gear works specifically, but likely it stores each kind of door as an object ID in data, then when the player interacts with it the game uses the object ID to decide to do.  There's probably additional data for doors telling the game engine where the door leads, but you'd have to reverse-engineer the game itself in order to get the actual details.